# how to expand list items to the width of the parent

Tags: html, css

I need to expand each image to the width of the parent li element.
Images need to be in 2 rows and both rows need to be expanded to the width of the parent ul to fill all the width of the page in the section#cuisines here http://www.recipes.cc.ua/. 
[this is the mockup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tuZkr.jpg)

Comment: use width 100% in img tag like this <img src="images/main_content/cuisines/italian.png" width="100%">

Comment: yes, it  works! thank you!

Comment: @code.rider quick solution, but this stretches the images.

Comment: no because height has no property it should scaled with width

Comment: @code.rider, correct. I guess I worded it wrong. I meant that it up-scales the pictures making them less crisp.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added the following properties to your css:

```
ul.cuisine_list {
  display: inline-block;
}
ul.cuisine_listitem {
  text-align: center;
  width: 20%;
  float: left;
}
ul.cuisine_listitem p {
  left: 5%;
}
```

Comment: but then the footer goes up and appears under the images

Comment: @Olga setting the container to `display: inline-block` should solve that - as I have in the code above. Does it not work?

Comment: the reason was in float of previous elements